# jQuery datepicker is not appearing on click

Tags: html, datepicker

I'm just trying to add a date picker to my form on CodePen, here is the link: http://codepen.io/kaisle/pen/QwagVE. It is very simple jQuery that I forked from someone else, all I did was add the basic datepicker from the jQuery website:

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the placement of the function. I'm having the same problem with the timepicker. Thanks!

Comment: It tells you in the console - "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", datepicker() isn't defined. Is jQueryUI available on codepen? Not used it before so I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Looks like you need to click on the cog in the 'JS' pane heading and enable latest jQuery and jQueryUI - works for me then.

Comment: Thanks gratz. I did have "jQuery" selected in the pane heading, but you're right that when I choose "jQuery and jQueryUI" the datepicker works. However the timepicker is still not working, see any problems with that?

Comment: There is no any inbuilt jquery timepicker. So you have to use third party plugin.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. Thanks user3134634.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import jquery and jquery-ui.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

jquery doesn't provides inbuilt timepicker. So you need to use third party plugin. Here bootstrap-timepicker link.

```
http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the JS settings to 'jQuery & jQuery UI (Base Theme)' and then fix the two errors like below.

```
$(this).on('blur', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
  $(this).parent('.field').removeClass('active');
  }
});

if ($(this).val() !== '') $(this).parent('.field').addClass('active');
```

Here is the link with a solution

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwQwER